# Blue smoke when starting cold after fixing the PCV valve

Tags: toyota, corolla, pcv-valve

I’m trying to clean the PCV valve on my 2004 Toyota Corolla Altis when I discovered that it’s stuck closed because someone intentionally covered it with plastic rubber. I bought the car 2nd hand about 7 years ago so I’m not sure why they would intentionally block the pcv valve from breathing out. I soon realized that might explain the carbon build up i saw about a year ago when i got the top cover gaskets replaced. I can also see it inside the engine when the oil cap is removed. There’s also carbon build up and oil from the breather hose.

I fixed the pcv valve and cleaned the breather hose but now whenever I start the engine cold the car puffs some blue-ish smoke for a few seconds and disappear. There’s no smoke when on a normal operating temperature and driving.